# Why doesn't the download function work from app deployed on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, jupyter-notebook, download, geemap

```
global down_path
down_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'TempDownload')
if not os.path.exists(down_path):
    os.mkdir(down_path)  # 如果不存在这个logs文件夹，就自动创建一个    
filename = os.path.join(down_path, localnow+'ssc.tif')
geemap.ee_export_image(ssc_intial, filename=filename, scale=110, region=roi, file_per_band=False)
```

[image]

When I clicked the button to download the file, it didn't work. But when I run it via a local host, it works perfectly

Comment: Are you using the add on to upload files ? If you are saving files in the filesystem, they will be erased at least once a day. This is crucial on Heroku, because your app’s dynos have an ephemeral filesystem. This means that all files that aren’t part of your application’s slug are lost whenever a dyno restarts or is replaced (this happens at least once daily). https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/simple-file-upload

Comment: hello bluesky and welcome to SO. `# 如果不存在这个logs文件夹，就自动创建一个` Please translate all code to English before posting